# Svn repository in a Git branch

Tags: svn, git, branch

I'm using git, git-svn, I managed to import a svn repository into git master, using git svn clone REPO.
My question is:
if I want to use git master for my changes that don't need to go into SVN, and so I want the svn part being part of a git branch, what should I do?

Idea?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVN repo you cloned is already considered a "remote" branch within git.  By default that remote is named `remotes/git-svn`.  If you elect to track that from your `master` with `git-svn rebase` then the changes will be reflected in `master`.  However, you can limit yourself to `git-svn fetch` to keep `remotes/git-svn` updated with SVN revisions and merge from that by hand into `master` or any branch you choose.